# How to handle too many chart control images in directory folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have an application deployed on iis6. The problem is that whenever i view a chart image in the application, the program automatic generate an image and store it in my directory folder. Then it keeps accumulating and accumulating when more and more people are using the feature.

I believe there is something wrong with the storage method in my web.config file? please do help me, i tried a number of ways already. please also tell me if you need to see more codes.

web.config:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=1;deleteAfterServicing=false; webDevServerUseConfigSettings=false;"/>
  </appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set `deleteAfterServicing=true`, this will clean up your images folder.

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456629.aspx):

> *deleteAfterServicing*
>
> Whether the image should be deleted after successful download from a
>   client.
>
> The default value is **true**.

Alternatively, as the default is true, you can simply remove the `deleteAfterServicing` setting:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" 
         value="storage=file;timeout=1;webDevServerUseConfigSettings=false;"/>
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 Options.

1. You can use **value="storage=memory;deleteAfterServicing=true;"** in your appsetting.
2. You can use temp directory and delete manually if you are concerned about RAM being used. **value= "url=~/App_Data/ChartImageTemp/;"**

hope it helps.